# how to read command output from serial device using python

Tags: python, serial-port

I have an embedded linux device and here's what I would like to do using python:

1. Get the device console over serial port. I can do it like this:

   `>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB-17', 115200, timeout=1)`
2. Now I want to run a `tail` command on the embedded device command line, like this:

   `# tail -f /var/log/messages`

and capture the o/p and display on my python >>> console.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about python programming?

Comment: @ MIke No I don't. I purpose fully left my question vague so as to get more suggestions.

Comment: I have re-read this question several times and I don't see an actual question here, so @Mike isn't the only who is wondering what your specific question is. Without making your question clearer, you may not get **any** suggestions. Where is the python script being run? Where is the tail command being run? Are you expecting the python script to put messages into `/var/etc/messages`? Do you want the python script to run `tail` and output those messages to the serial port?

Comment: Sorry. I am connecting to embedded device over serial port using python API. Now I want to run the tail on the device console ( python is on host computer). I want to capture that o/p from device and display it on the host python shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the file inside python and keep readign from it. If needed be, in another thread:

```
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB-17', 115200, timeout=1)
>>> output = open("/var/log/messages", "rb")
```

And inside any program loop, just do:

```
data = output.read()
print(data)
```

If you want it to just go printing on the console as you keep doing other stuff, type
in something like:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
class Display(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.output.read()
            if data: print(data)
            sleep(1)


t = Display()
t.output = output
t.start()
```

Comment: That not what I was asking. Sorry I it was not clear. Please see edited question.

Comment: I am trying to run tail on the embedded device prompt and getting o/p on linux host prompt.

Answer (score 0):

very first you need to get log-in into the device.
then you can run the specified command on that device.
note:command which you are going to run must be supported by that device.

Now after opening a serial port using open() you need to find the login prompt using Read() and then write the username using write(), same thing repeat for password.

once you have logged-in you can now run the commands you needed to execute